# Could I add a new Gmail email address to my Google account?

Tags: gmail, google-account

If I delete my Gmail address from my Google account ([with this method](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177)), then could I register a new one? Google support pages don't say anything about it, sadly. I think maybe it is possible because you can register a Google account first and add a Gmail address later, but maybe it is allowed only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Your Gmail address *is* your Google account. You can't separate them. If you delete the Gmail mailbox by using the help page you have linked to, you'll not be able to create a new Gmail address and link it to that account.

You'll need to create a new Gmail/Google account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, for the records, here is the article about this topic: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I would say so. Your Gmail account is entirely separate to your Google Services account these days. Note though that you won't be able to reuse tour old Gmail name as it would be archived.

Comment: "Yes, I would say so" is not enough, I have to be sure on this before I delete my gmail address.

Comment: But how do you link the new Gmail address to the existing Google Account  (which probably already has a username of the form `oldaddress@gmail.com`)? Wouldn't the process of creating a new Gmail address create a new Google Account?

Comment: This is a wrong answer, after deleting the Gmail address related to the account, you can't add a new Gmail address